# Getting text from multiple webpages(Pagination) in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, pagination

I wanted to extract text from multiple pages. Currently, I am able to extract data from the first page but I want to append and go to muliple pages and extract the data from pagination. I have written this simple code which extracts data from the first page. I am not able to extract the data from multiple pages which is dynamic in number.

`

```
element_list = []
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
base_url = "XYZ"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(base_url)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(50)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'all-my-groups')))

l = []
l = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'alias-wrapper sim-ellipsis sim-list--shortId')]")

for i in l:
    print(i.text)
```

`

I have shared the images of class if this could help from pagination.

[image]

If we could extract the automate and extract from all the pages that would be awesome. Also, I am new so please pardon me for asking silly questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what would the url be, if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

You have provided the code just for the previous page button. I guess you need to go to the next page until next page exists. As I don't know what site we are talking about I can only guess its behavior. So I'm assuming the button 'next' disappears when no next page exists. If so, it can be done like this:

```py
element_list = []
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
base_url = "XYZ"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(base_url)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(50)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'all-my-groups')))

l = []
l = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'alias-wrapper sim-ellipsis sim-list--shortId')]")

while True:
    try:
        next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@label="Next page"]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
    next_page.click()
    l.extend(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'alias-wrapper sim-ellipsis sim-list--shortId')]"))
    

for i in l:
    print(i.text)
```

To be able to catch the exception this import has to be added:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

Also note that the method `find_elements_by_xpath` is deprecated and it would be better to replace this line:

```
l = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'alias-wrapper sim-ellipsis sim-list--shortId')]")
```

by this one:

```
l = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'alias-wrapper sim-ellipsis sim-list--shortId')]")
```